# How to handle bitmap array if pdf size exceeds?

Tags: android

In our application we are converting byte array of pdf into images. We are storing those images into bitmap array format, but if bitmapp array size goes beyond 15 application gets crashed.As solution i was planning to load 5 images at initial stage. If user scrolls on 6th page then 1 ,2 ,3 pages would be removed from array so that memory can be managed.Again on back scrolling again removed pages would be generate again.
I need some solutions?
How to handle this scenario.
Please do needful help.

Thanks,
AA.